# Apache blocks websocket protocol for Shiny

Tags: r, apache, websocket, shiny, shinyproxy

I've deployed a web-app using Shinyproxy and Shiny.

If I go to http://localhost/mycontextpath/app/01_example everything works perfectly. The *ProxyPass* and *ProxyPassReverse* have been set up in Apache and now I can go directly to http://mywebsite.org/mycontextpath/app/01_example to use my app.

The problem is that the screen greys out automatically. I know it's a problem with Apache as the browser debugger print this message:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://mywebsite.org/mycontextpath/wonderful_hypatia/websocket/.
```

I've tried to add this line to my Apache configuration:

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.+)/websocket" "ws://localhost:8146/mycontextpath/$1/websocket" keepalive=On
```

But it doesn't seems to work.

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to stick to Apache as your proxy server, read this post [Running Shiny Server with a Proxy](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy).

Or if you are open to using Nginx, Shinyproxy website actually has the detailed [Nginx configuration](https://www.shinyproxy.io/security/) on its website under the **HTTPS (SSL / TLS)** section. That's also the configuration I'm using and it works just fine.